# How to pass docker container flags via kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Hi I am running kubernetes cluster where I run mailhog container.

But I need to run it with own docker run parameter. If I would run it in docker directly. I would use command:

```
docker run  mailhog/mailhog -auth-file=./auth.file
```

But I need to run it via Kubernetes pod. My pod looks like:

```
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: mailhog
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      revisionHistoryLimit: 1
      strategy:
          type: RollingUpdate
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: mailhog
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: mailhog
            image: us.gcr.io/com/mailhog:1.0.0
            ports:
            - containerPort: 8025
```

How to achieve to run Docker container with parameter -auth-file=./auth.file via kubernetes. Thanks.

I tried adding under `containers`

```
        command: ["-auth-file", "/data/mailhog/auth.file"]
```

but then I get

```
 Failed to start container with docker id 7565654 with error: Error response from daemon: Container command '-auth-file' not found or does not exist.
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

thanks to @lang2

here is my deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mailhog
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  strategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mailhog
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: secrets-volume
        secret:
            secretName: mailhog-login
      containers:
      - name: mailhog
        image: us.gcr.io/com/mailhog:1.0.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 70m
            memory: 30Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 20Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets-volume
          mountPath: /data/mailhog
          readOnly: true
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8025
        - containerPort: 1025
        args:
          - "-auth-file=/data/mailhog/auth.file"
```

Answer (score 11):

In kubernetes, `command` is equivalent of `ENTRYPOINT`. In your case, `args` should be used.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#container-v1-core

Comment: This link seems to be dead.

Answer (score 9):

You are on the right track. It's just that you also need to include the name of the binary in the `command` array as the first element. You can find that out by looking​ in the respective `Dockerfile` (`CMD` and/or `ENTRYPOINT`).

In this case:
`command: ["Mailhog", "-auth-file", "/data/mailhog/auth.file"]`

Answer (score 2):

I needed similar task (my aim was passing the application profile to app) and what I did is the following:

Setting an environment variable in Deployment section of the kubernetes yml file.

```
env:
- name: PROFILE
  value: "dev"
```

Using this environment variable in dockerfile as command line argument.

```
CMD java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=${PROFILE} /opt/app/xyz-service-*.jar
```