# Add docker runtime arguments to helm chart

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a docker image that I run with specific runtime arguments. When I install a helm chart to deploy the kubernetes pod with this image, the output from the pod is different from when I use 'docker run.' I found that I should use command and args parameters in the values.yml file and the templates/deployment directory but I'm still not getting the desired output.

I've tried different variations from these links but no luck:
[How to pass docker run flags via kubernetes pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098164/how-to-pass-docker-run-flags-via-kubernetes-pod)
[How to pass dynamic arguments to a helm chart that runs a job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636571/how-to-pass-dynamic-arguments-to-a-helm-chart-that-runs-a-job)
[How to pass arguments to Docker container in Kubernetes or OpenShift through command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093384/how-to-pass-arguments-to-docker-container-in-kubernetes-or-openshift-through-com)

Here's the docker run command:
`docker run --it --rm --network=host --ulimit rtptrio=0 --cap-add=sys_nice --ipc=private --sysctl fs.msqueue.msg_max="10000" image_name:tag`

Comment: Which chart you want to deploy? What helm version are you using? How looks your helm command, which parameter did you use in command and which changes you made in `templates/deployment` and `valuses.yaml`?

Answer (score 3):

Please try something like that:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  securityContext:
    capabilities:
      add: ["SYS_NICE"]
  containers:
  - name: main
    image: image_name:tag
```